# With py.test, what is the best way to do test inclusion-exclusion from the command line?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a large test suite with a deep tree structure. I want to run certain portions of that tree based on command line flags. For example, if I had the directories *a/b/c*, *a/b/d*, *a/b/e*, and *f/g* I might want to run all the tests within *a/b* and *f* except those within *a/b/c*. For various reasons, I can't change the tests themselves to accommodate this, so I can't use markers. (The goal here is to be able to run various slices of tests without having to change any files.)

It seems like I could use *py.test --ignore a/b/c -- a/b f*, but I was wondering if there isn't a better way? Is there a way that doesn't require me to change the rootdir? Is there any way to do this that would be portable between Linux and Windows?

Also, while I'm only interested in filtering by directories and files for now, is there a way to extend this to filter by test classes and methods? The -k flag seems like it can do this, but I can't use directory names with it. *-k 'a/b and not a/b/c'* give a divide by zero error.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://pytest.org/latest/example/markers.html#selecting-tests-based-on-their-node-id

Comment: No, not quite. I didn't know you could select individual tests like that, but otherwise, I went over most of those options in my question. Also, it doesn't seem like --ignore works beyond the file level.

Comment: Can you add a custom `conftest.py`? If so, you could write a hook to add markers based on paths [like here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/develop/tests/conftest.py#L15-L30).

Comment: Something like that could work, but first I'd like to verify that there's no existing options to do this.